# Codeigniter A PHP Error was encountered

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

I'm getting the following error

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   offset:3

error at the last line

```
private function date_conversion($str){
  $this->lang->load('calendar');
    $arr = explode(' ', $str);
    $month = array(
        $this->lang->line('cal_january') => '01', $this->lang->line('cal_february') => '02', $this->lang->line('cal_march') => '03', 
        $this->lang->line('cal_april') => '04', $this->lang->line('cal_may') => '05', $this->lang->line('cal_june') => '06', 
        $this->lang->line('cal_july') => '07', $this->lang->line('cal_august') => '08', $this->lang->line('cal_september') => '09', 
        $this->lang->line('cal_october') => '10', $this->lang->line('cal_november') => '11', $this->lang->line('cal_december') => '12', 
    );
    return $arr[3].'-'.$month[$arr[2]].'-'.($arr[1]<10?'0'.$arr[1]:$arr[1]);
 }
```

and the first proccess from this

```
'date_of_birth'=>$field['adult']['date_of_birth']?$this->date_conversion($this->input->post('adult_date_of_birth_'.$i)):NULL,
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The last line, `$arr[3]` is failing, because the array `$arr` doesn't have enough items. I'm afraid I can't help any further, because it totally depends on `$str` what the outcome will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably $arr doesn't have a index 3, if you know it will have only 3 elements then that will be index 2

change:
`return $arr[3].'-'.$month[$arr[2]].'-'.($arr[1]<10?'0'.$arr[1]:$arr[1]);`

for: 
`return $arr[2].'-'.$month[$arr[1]].'-'.($arr[0]<10?'0'.$arr[0]:$arr[0]);`

Comment: What's the value of $str?

Comment: var_dump($arr) & post it here

Comment: i'm not sure but this is when input post calendar

Comment: echo $str copy and paste here so we can see what it contains

Comment: to further help you, like I said I will need to see the post values, do you have an example on how $str is supposed to look like?

Comment: i found the problem from datepicker...and now works fine

Answer (score 0):

You are simply assuming that the string you are exploding to an array will have 4 parts. A string like "My Nice String" will end up as an array("My", "Nice", "String"); where index 0 will have the value of "My", index 1 value of "Nice, and index 2 value of "String".

Take note, that array indexes are zero-based, meaning that the first element will normally begin with an index of 0, and not 1. Unless the array has been defined differently.